# Prevent AWS instance from stopping

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I would like to trap the EC2 stop/terminate event. Once the event is trapped I should be able to stop the event. The stop event can be done only from a particular ip address. I would like to automate the workflow.

I tried using SNS and register a HTTP endpoint. But unable to stop the stop event.

Comment: what do you mean with stop the event? prevent the ec2 shutdown?

Comment: Stopping the instance from the console or cli or api.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great idea to do this, but have you considered modifying the IAM policies associated with your users/roles so that ec2:StopInstances is denied unless the request came from a specific IP address (using Condition/NotIpAddress/aws:SourceIp).

Comment: Are you aware AWS providing hooks/callback when stop instance operation is done? This will allow me to write code so that we can perform checks and allow the events/operation to continue?

Answer (score 0):

first add termination protection on your instance. 
then you have to enable cloud-trail to log API calls to see the abuser failed calls. 
you can fully prevent certain users from terminating instance by IAM. 
it's not good to rely on IP.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the flow  a) Write SNS HTTPS endpoint to handle event b) Handle Stopping event c) In the stopping event I use API to prevent the stop instance based on IAM. Can you let me know if I'm correct? Or can you share the code snippets for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Termination Protection on your EC2 instance. That way you can controll wheteher the instance can or can't be deleted through the CLI or API. You can add an IAM role that has access to call the CLI or the API.

Termination Protection doesn't stop a user from initiating a shutdown of the system from the instance. You might have to have a look at that aswell.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for protecting the Stop operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook for these API operations.

An instance can also be stopped from *inside* the instance (e.g. `sudo halt` or `sudo poweroff`), and EC2 will stop or even terminate the instance in that case, based on the instance's [`InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior) attribute, which can be set to stop (default) or terminate the instance.  In fact, an instance with this option set to terminate the instance is also immune to "termination protection," which is an attribute that only blocks termination via the API (or the console, which also calls the API).

However, EC2 *autoscaling* does have [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) that allow you to intercept autoscaling's *proposed* stop or termination, before the calls to the EC2 API are made by autoscaling.  This does not sound likely to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to "trap" operations.

Instead, you should **limit the people (IAM Users) who have permission** to issue the Stop or Terminate commands.

By default, IAM Users have no permission. They are then granted permission to perform operations in AWS. If you do not wish people to use the Stop command, then do not give them `ec2:StopInstances` permissions or at least limit the permissions to only a limited set of instances on which they can perform the command.

For example, it might be possible to grant permission to Stop instances *unless* the instances have a particular tag.